# Can it always be determined if an animal is a carnivore, omnivore, or herbivore by its teeth or are there exceptions?

Tags: zoology, diet, teeth

Take the panda, for instance, it has canines but it's an herbivore. However, are there are other aspects of its teeth where one could still tell that it's an herbivore? Do the teeth always relay the information about whether an animal is a carnivore, omnivore, or herbivore?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! With the panda example you seem to have answered your own question. You also might find the [answers to this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15937/) to be of interest.  ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: @tyersome I didn't actually answer the question, there may be other aspects to a panda's teeth that tell what its diet is, rather than just are there big canines or not. That was just an example where maybe more investigation is needed, or maybe one couldn't tell just by the teeth, I don't know,  hence the question.